# How to loop once when a receive a notification python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a desktop notifier to receive a notification when a certain streamer on Twitch is streaming.
I'm using 2 loops. Both of them an if statement, the first one when the person is streaming and the other inside to when is streaming and I haven't received any notification (I don't want 15 notifications about the same) but I haven't found how to do it because if I declare the variable notification the variable reset and I always get the same value. I think my main problem is in the function called stream_notification.
Moreover, when this person is streaming, the variable streaming_state = 1.

```
def streamer_data():
   # Rest of the code omitted because not relevant
    stream_data = stream.json();
    streaming_state = len(stream_data['data'])
    return streaming_state, streamer_name

def stream_notification(streaming_state,streamer_name):
    notified = 0
    if streaming_state == 1:  # Enter to the statement if it's streaming
        if streaming_state != notified:  # Enter to the statement if it's streaming and if it has not been notified
            for repeat in range(1):
                notifyMe("Twitch", f"{streamer_name} is live")
            notified = streaming_state
    time.sleep(5)

def notifyMe(title,message):
    notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_icon = 'Clock_icon.ico',
        timeout = 5
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        streaming_state,streamer_name = streamer_data()
        stream_notification(streaming_state,streamer_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of errors I came up with an idea. I created another loop after the if statement who checks if that specific person is streaming to keep my programme waiting for the streamer to disconnect (it doesn't make sense that it kept running if I already got the notification) to run again from the beginning. So my solution looks like this:

```
def streamer_data():
   # Rest of the code omitted because not relevant
    stream_data = stream.json();
    streaming_state = len(stream_data['data'])
    return streaming_state, streamer_name

def stream_notification():
    streaming_state, streamer_name = streamer_data()
    notified = 0
    if streaming_state == 1:  # Enter to the statement if it's streaming
        for repeat in range(1):
            notifyMe("Twitch", f"{streamer_name} is live")
        notified = streaming_state
    while notified == 1:
        streaming_state, streamer_name = streamer_data()
        if streaming_state == 0:
            notified = 0
    time.sleep(1)

def notifyMe(title,message):
    notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_icon = 'Clock_icon.ico',
        timeout = 1
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        stream_notification()
```